# vuejs plugin undetected. ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at eval

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a project using Vue 3. I tried to add
[bootstrap-material-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker) into my project. This is how I import it on my Vue component file.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
// ..

import 'bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js'
import 'bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css'

// ..
</script>
```

I get an error when trying to run that. From the error, I can tell that somehow jquery is not detected on my app. It's weird since I believe I've added the jquery plugin definition into `vue.config.js` file.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '/public/',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
}
```

On the browser console below is the error that I get:

> vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1905 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at eval (bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js?5260:1295)
> at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js (vendors~PublicSignUp.js:76)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:768)
> at fn (app.js:131)
> at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/pages/public/SignUp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:6)
> at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/pages/public/SignUp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (PublicSignUp.js:11)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:768)
> at fn (app.js:131)
> at eval (SignUp.vue?8585:1)
> at Module../src/pages/public/SignUp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (PublicSignUp.js:80)

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw [similar issue on github](https://github.com/phegman/vue-mapbox-gl/issues/25), turns out I just need to wrap the `plugins` inside `configureWebpack`.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '/public/',
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                '$': 'jquery',
                'jquery': 'jquery',
                'jQuery': 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                'moment': 'moment'
            })
        ]
    }
}
```